# How do I resolve the (ModuleNotFoundError: No module name '_tkinter') for WINDOWS 10, Python 3.7

Tags: windows-10, python3

Windows 10
Python 3.7.4
OSGeo4W Shell

`C:\ActiveTcl\bin` is in the PATH
tkinter folder is located in `C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Python37/lib/tkinter`

```
python test_data_analysis.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_data_analysis.py", line 4, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2355, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 221, in switch_backend
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _backend_tk
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

under py3_env I have attempted importing:

- `_tkinter`
- `tkinter`
- `_Tkinter`
- `Tkinter`

importing `tk` works.

Oddly enough, when I run from the Python 3.7.4 shell `import tkinter` works, but `import tk` does not.

Running `python -m (all tkinter varieties)` does not work.

Running `python -m pip install (all tkinter varieties)` does not work.

I'm on the struggle bus with this one. Any suggestions that are for Windows would be great.

Answer (score -1):

Please download (or rerun) the Python installer for your version - in your case 3.7.4 .
In the installation Menu choose to modify existing installation and in next screen select "tcl/tk' option. 
Proceed with the install until the end.
It should work afterwords. So far its the only option to add it on Windows.